# TypeScript - Transform type's properties to types of their children

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type which would transform a generic type based on its children. To clarify what I mean, here's a simplified example, the use case is a bit different:

Original type

```
type FormFields = {
    username: {
        type: string,
        name: 'User Name'
    },
    password: {
        type: string,
        name: 'Password (must be strong)'
    };
}
```

I'd like to transform it so it could be used as

```
const userInput: UserInput<FormFields> = ...;
```

where the type of `userInput` is essentially

```
{username: string, password: string}
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this, but it gives me an error:

```
type UserInput<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]['type'];
}
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need a constraint on `T` to let TS know that `T` will have the required `type` property on its members:

```
type UserInput<T extends Record<string, { type: string}>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]['type'];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYwJYQDYBMDOUC8UA3gLABQUlUArjhAgHYCGSEAXMeVd1KJBzmAJUDAOYAaLj0rNWHAOQBVOgigA5FhHlTKAX0kUqYJjhwB3RFg6lD0vuyiDhYg9JmaFABRPnLUABRItMBQAEbQTnBiAJTatlC6ANzkuuQAxlGCNCoAkgxg1MAcyvR5BcAAPPDIaJi4AHwENtzGphYIVlAARF2uVLT0sg49KeT2UCUIZYUVACpQEAAewBAMuFAAShAZHRVOIhLEvOAO+2K69Y2EzVQA2gDSUCJQANYQIHAAZlCzALocswev1u8ns8l+yTIuiAA)